# Bootstrap padding or margin between elements on same line

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, margin, padding

I am new to bootstrap and I have the following code.

```
 <form name="filesearch" id="filesearch" method="post" action="index.cfm">
      <div class="input-group col-lg-5">
           <span class="input-group-addon"><input name="searchBy" id="mfrmtrlRadio" type="radio">Manufacturer</span>
           <input id="mfr" name="mfr" type="text" class="form-control">
           <span class="input-group-addon">Material Name</span>
           <input id="mtrlname" name="mtrlname" type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
 </form>
```

[image]

This is not an inline form and I am trying to put space between the first input and the second span. So between input id mfr and the span of Material Name.

Comment: I think you could create a class "input-group-addon-right" and add it to the Material Name span element. Then you should give that class a margin-left of what you desire. EDIT: Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/djuawovn/

Comment: The suggest you made and all the similar solutions I have tired only create the gray box around Material Name to be larger not create a gap.

Comment: Oh I see. You should make two new columns in your existing col-lg-5, in which you place each of your input fields and spans. When necessary you could give these new columns a class to add margins. I can provide you a jsfiddle tomorrow, just turned off my laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the grid instead of using multiple add-ons inside one group.

Place your inputs inside of XS columns, then reduce the padding of the columns so the space between the two inputs isn't as large.

See working Snippets.

*Sidenote: I places an additional example as the add-ons are so large that on a mobile device there is nearly no usable input space which may or may not matter.

```css
.no-gutter >[class*='col-'] {
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<hr>
<div class="well">
  <p>XS Columns</p>
</div>
<form role="form" method="post" id="myForm">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row no-gutter">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <input type="radio" aria-label="..."> Manufacturer</span>

          <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"> Material Name</span>

          <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<hr>
<div class="well">
  <p>SM Columns</p>
</div>
<form role="form" method="post" id="myForm">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row no-gutter">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <input type="radio" aria-label="..."> Manufacturer</span>

            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"> Material Name</span>

            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<hr>
```

Comment: Breaking up the column div from the input-group is the answer. So one div as the column and then a div as the input group.